# Howto add ipv6 to remoteip.conf

Tags: cloudflare

I'm trying to apply these configurations to my apache2 web server with the help of Cloudflare original documentation [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/restoring-visitor-ips/restoring-original-visitor-ips/). In the 4th step it says;

> 4. Define trusted proxy addresses by creating /etc/apache2/conf-available/remoteip.conf by entering the following code and  Cloudflare IPs:

```
RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 192.0.2.1 (example IP address)
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 192.0.2.2 (example IP address)
(repeat for all Cloudflare IPs listed at https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)
```

In the link there are 2 lists, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6. I can add IPv4 list to remoteip.conf file without any issue but I don't know how to add IPv6 list to the file. Actually I even don't know if IPv4 list is a must or not.
Is there anyone facing with this, how can I add the IPv6 list?

Comment: Thanks to sjr, who replied me in this link https://community.cloudflare.com/t/howto-add-ipv6-to-remoteip-conf/599722/3